# find mode of filedescriptor return by open(const char *filename, int flags[, mode_t mode]) function

Tags: c, compiler-optimization

while compiling a C program with `-O1` or greater flag, compiler is giving the error `call to '__open_missing_mode' declared with attribute error: open with O_CREAT or O_TMPFILE in second argument needs 3 arguments` .

From the search on internet I found that Open must need to pass `mode_t` with `O_CREAT` option. How to find the default mode of file descriptor that return with `open` function of 2 arg earlier.

Comment: What do you mean default mode? If you pass `O_CREAT` and not a third argument with a filename that doesn't already exist, you're getting into undefined behavior when `open()` tries to use that non-existent argument.

Comment: And if the file already exists, its permissions are whatever they are, and you can find those with `fstat()`.

Comment: It is perfectly compiling if I don't pass `-O1` flag. So what is that `mode_t` taken here?

Comment: *It is perfectly compiling if I don't pass `-O1` flag*  That doesn't mean the code is correct.  There is no default mode.  If you call `open()` with `O_CREAT` and do not pass a thirde `mode_t` argument, as @Shawn noted you'll get undefined behavior that most likely manifests as a "random" file mode, but you could crash your process.